# How can I detect transparent areas in a sprite in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 1024x1024 pixel sprite with some transparent areas in it. I am rendering it on a game scene using Sprite Renderer. Is there any way check whether the pixel at mouse position is transparent or not when the mouse is hovered over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could cast ray and get the world position of our hit point, Here I am assuming your `SpriteRenderer` has a collider.

```
private RaycastHit CastRay()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
    return hit;
}
```

Then we need a method to convert that world space into texture coordinates

```
public Vector2 TextureSpaceCoord(Vector3 worldPos) {
    float ppu = _sprite.pixelsPerUnit;

    Vector2 localPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPos) * ppu;

    var texSpacePivot = new Vector2(_sprite.rect.x, _sprite.rect.y) + _sprite.pivot;
    Vector2 texSpaceCoord = texSpacePivot + localPos;

    return texSpaceCoord;
}
```

Once we get the texture coordinates we could just use `GetPixel()` of `Texture2D` to get the color

```
private void PickColor()
{
    RaycastHit hit = CastRay();
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Vector2 coord = TextureSpaceCoord(hit.point);
        Color selectedColor = _sprite.texture.GetPixel((int) coord.x, (int) coord.y);

        // Here you can check if color is transparent
        if(selectedColor == Color.clear){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

You could call the `PickColor()` in `Update()`, `_camera` would be `Camera.main` and `_sprite` would be the `Sprite` of your `SpriteRenderer`